# Nextjs how to type Error page with typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

How can type an nextjs Error page with Typescript

I've tried with:

```
interface ErrorProps {
  statusCode: number;
}
function Error({ statusCode }: ErrorProps) {
  return (
    <p>
      {statusCode
        ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
        : "An error occurred on client"}
    </p>
  );
}

interface InitialProps {
  res: NextApiResponse;
  err: NextApiResponse;
}
Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }: InitialProps) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
  return { statusCode };
};
```

but not sure it's the right way

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No Error but I'm new at nextjs so I'd like to know if I'm right or not :) or there was a better way

Comment: The same way you'd type any other page in Next.js, see [How to type a page component with props in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560905/how-to-type-a-page-component-with-props-in-next-js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Next's own documentation ->

> pages/_error.js is only used in production. In development you’ll get an error with the call stack to know where the error originated from.

Answer (score 9):

I am working perfectly with the code below. Check this!

See more details on [Next.js error page for typescript](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props#typescript)

```js
import { NextPage, NextPageContext } from 'next';


interface Props {
    statusCode?: number
}

const Error: NextPage<Props> = ({ statusCode }) => {
    return (
        <p>
        {statusCode
            ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
            : "An error occurred on client"}
        </p>
    );
  }
  
  Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }: NextPageContext) => {
    const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404
    return { statusCode }
  }
  
  export default Error
```