# How to type a page component with props in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm looking to correctly annotate the `Home` function component's parameters, but am running into a little bit of trouble. I was hoping to annotate it like: `{ events }: { events: Event[] }`, but am getting the TypeScript error, `Property 'events' does not exist on type '{ children: ReactNode }' in Next.js`.

Next does a lot of wizardry behind the scenes, so I am not sure how I can fix this. Any ideas?

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import axios from '../lib/axios';

import { Event } from '../ts/interfaces';

const Home: NextPage = ({ events }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {events.map((event: Event) => (
        <div key={event.title}>{event.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get<Event[]>(`${process.env.API_URL}/events`);

  return {
    props: { events: res.data },
  };
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Could you shows us what NextPage is? Might be useful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass the `Home` props type (in your case `{ events: Event[] }`) as the generic type to `NextPage`.

```js
import { Event } from '../ts/interfaces';

const Home: NextPage<{ events: Event[] }> = ({ events }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {events.map((event: Event) => (
                <div key={event.title}>{event.title}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Interesting how the official typescript example doesn't include NextPage, nor how to add with a custom prop type.

Comment: @wanna_coder101 Weirdly enough the only place where `NextPage` is referenced in the docs is here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props#typescript.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was trying to pass a `PageProps` interface, but kept getting an error of `Type '({ posts }: { posts: PageProps; }) => { posts: PageProps; }' is not assignable to type 'NextPage<{ posts: PageProps; }, { posts: PageProps; }>'.` Couldn't understand the duplication.

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for a type of "app directory" page (next 13+).
You'll have to make your own, I couldn't find a type to import from the next package, so:

```
interface IPageProps {
  params: { your_dynamic_prop_here: string };
  searchParams: Record<string | string[], string | undefined>
}
```

```
export default function Page(props: IPageProps) {...}
```