# Type '{ songs: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes' NEXTJS/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a very simple script.

Here is the index.tsx of my Next APP :

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import SongsList from '../components/SongsList/SongsList'
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

const SONGS: Song[] = [
  {
    title: 'Birdseye Blues',
    artist: 'Chris Haugen',
    file: 'Birdseye Blues - Chris Haugen.mp3',
    image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598387993441-a364f854c3e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1176&q=80'
  },
  {
    title: 'Depth Fuse',
    artist: 'French Fuse',
    file: 'Depth Fuse - French Fuse.mp3',
    image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617136785693-54b279bddfeb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80'
  },
  {
    title: 'Duh Fuse',
    artist: 'French Fuse',
    file: 'Duh Fuse - French Fuse.mp3',
    image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614247912229-26a7e2114c0a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80'
  }
]

interface Song {
  title: string;
  artist: string;
  file: string;
  image: string
}

const Home: NextPage<Song> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <SongsList songs={props.songs} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async() => {
  return {
    props: {
      songs: SONGS
    },
    revalidate: 3600
  }
}

export default Home
```

Sadly, I have an error right there :

```
<SongsList songs={props.songs} />
```

The error is saying :

```
(property) songs: any
Type '{ songs: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'songs' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

Here is my SongsList.tsx component :

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import Song from '../Song/Song'

type Song = {
    title: string;
    artist: string;
    file: string;
    image: string;
}
  
const SongsList: NextPage<Song> = ( props: any ) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.songs.map(function(e: any) {
                    return (
                        <Song song={e} key={e.title} />
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default SongsList;
```

What did I do wrong there ?

Edit : I have tried all the solutions below, but no solutions are working, I have edited and added SongList.tsx for Bao Huynh Lam

Thank you for your help :) !

Comment: Pleas show code for your SongList component

Comment: You have to type `Home` as `const Home: NextPage<{ songs: Song[] }>`. See related question/answer: [How to type a page component with props in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560905/how-to-type-a-page-component-with-props-in-next-js).

Comment: @juliomalves I have already done this solution but didn't work sadly

Comment: Your `SongsList` is also incorrectly typed. It's not a page, so you shouldn't use `NextPage` to type it. In addition to my suggestion above for `Home`, use the following for `SongList` instead: `const SongsList = (props: { songs: Song[] }) => { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is your mistake:

```
const Home: NextPage<Song> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <SongsList songs={props.songs} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Chenge to:

```
const Home: NextPage<Song> = (props) => {
  const myProps = { 
    term: this.props.songs
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <SongsList {...myProps} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you durmex for your answer, sadly there is still the same error.

Comment: I updatet this, try again

Comment: I have still the same error :(