# Passing state from _app to pages with typescript in next.js

Tags: typescript, redux, next.js, use-state

I have a state which I would like to set in one page and then access in another page. My solution is to create the state in `_app.tsx` and then pass it to each page.

My understanding is I can create the state in `_app.tsx` like this

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('')
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <Component
        {...pageProps}
        setAccessToken={setAccessToken}
        accessToken={accessToken}
      />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

How can I then access the state and setState functions in my pages? I tried

```
const Home: NextPage = ({setAccessToken}) => { 
...}
```

But I get the error: `Property 'setAccessToken' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)`

How can I read the state I set in `_app.tsx`? Or am I going about this all wrong and should just use redux?

Comment: You should type the `Home` component as `const Home: NextPage<{ accessToken: string, setAccessToken: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> }>`. See [How to type a page component with props in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560905/how-to-type-a-page-component-with-props-in-next-js).

Comment: However, as @ToniBardinaComas pointed out, you may want to use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make the state available to whatever components need it, rather than prop drilling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `typescript` error that indicates that the prop `setAccessToken` is not expected for the `Component`. You can get rid of this error by updating/extending the `Component` interface inside `AppProps`. Btw what you are trying to do is very similar to the `React.Context` API. I would suggest using it instead of doing it yourself. You will get many advantages from doing so, like not having to send props all the way through to get/set the value on deeply nested child components.

Comment: Hi some questions about your answer: 1) How would I update/extend the Component interface inside appProps? 2) I only really set and read the AccessToken in one place each. Would you still recommend Context over state?